# Use REGEX with grep on Debian

Tags: regex, shell, debian

I try to use regex in my scripts, and I can't do what I want. I think I'm doing it wrong!

I have this string :
**mywebsite.fr/details.php?id=123456**

I'm trying to get this part:
**details.php?id=123456**

I'm using:

```
echo "http://mywebsite.fr/details.php?id=123456" | grep "/details(.*)/"
```

The command doesn't return any result ..
Is there anything I have misunderstood in my regex?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Quentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @eThang answered, you should not use `/`; grep does not use `/` as regular expression delimeter.

And if you want to get only the matched part, use `-o` option:

```
$ echo "http://mywebsite.fr/details.php?id=123456" | grep -o "details.*"    
details.php?id=123456
```

> ```
>    -o, --only-matching
>           Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on
>           a separate output line.
> ```
>
> *GNU grep  GREP(1)*

Comment: It works !
I don't know enough regex yet, thank you

I had to do too complicated !

Comment: If the string I need appears multiple times, how can I choose to stop to the first ? I don't know if you understand ^^'

Comment: I have a web page with this type of block :
`<p><a href="download.php?id=1234&name=file.torrent"></p>. . .<p><a href="download.php?id=1234&name=file.torrent"></p>`
I 'm using this command :
`grep -o "download.*.torrent"`

I have the entire block with content between both. You see ?

Comment: @mangasource, `echo '<p><a href="download.php?id=1234&name=file.torrent"></p>. . .<p><a href="download.php?id=1234&name=file.torrent"></p>' |  grep -o 'download.php[^"]*"' | head -1` ?

Comment: @mangasource, To see the difference, try it without `| head -1`

Comment: Okay, I see. I don't think it can happen, but how can I do if there is more than 2 occurences ?

Comment: @mangasource, I don't get it. Please post a separated question (with example if possible). I need sleep (1 am here)

Comment: hehe, no problem ! I think i found the solution. I have to work my skills with regex on linux ! ..

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the forward slashes.  They are not necessary with grep.

```
echo "http://mywebsite.fr/details.php?id=123456" | grep "details(.*)"
```